# how to make cursor appear where clicked in an EditText?

Tags: android-activity

I wrote a notepad Android app but when the user scrolls and clicks  say para 6 the keyboard comes and cursor appears on char no 1. How to solve this? Also tell Please how to implement find n replace.

Answer (score 0):

Ok got the second part...
EditText.setText(EditText.getText().toString().replace(findstring,replacement));

But what about the cursor problem?
If user clicks on char no n...
EditText.setSelection(n);

But how to find n?